# Android Room database pull

Tags: android, android-room

I use **Room database** to build my app.
After i create my database how i pull the database file with the following adb command:

adb exec-out run-as ---.---.--- cat /data/data/---.---.---/database/user-database.db > MyDB.db

Then when i try to oped that MyDB.db file with sqlitebrowser i see the message "*Invalid file format*".

**Why i can not open that file?**

**Is there an other better way to pull and examine the database file created by Android Room ??**

Thank you

Comment: If you use Stetho it will let you look at the DB, tables, tables contents and execute queries against the created tables.

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio 3, there is Device File Explorer at the right side (for me).[DeviceFileExplorer photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nFEL.png) 
Click it and go to your database file. for me, data> data> myPackageName> databases> [location of database file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Y6n.png)